# PowerShell - Extracting the Metadata of of files and grid viewing it

Tags: powershell, metadata, extract

Please see the following code:

```
# import .NET 4.5 compression utilities
Add-Type -As System.IO.Compression.FileSystem;

$zipArchives = Get-ChildItem "*.zip";
foreach($zipArchive in $zipArchives)
{
   $archivePath = $zipArchive.FullName;


$archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($archivePath);
try
{

    foreach($archiveEntry in $archive.Entries)
    {
        if($archiveEntry.FullName -notmatch '/$')
        {
            $tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();
            try
            {
                [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($archiveEntry, $tempFile, $true);
                $windowsStyleArchiveEntryName = $archiveEntry.FullName.Replace('/', '\');

                Select-String -pattern "<dc:title>.*</dc:title>" -path (Get-ChildItem $tempFile) | Select-Object @{Name="Path";Expression={Join-Path $archivePath (Split-Path $windowsStyleArchiveEntryName -Parent)}}
                #Select-String -pattern "<dc:title>.*</dc:title>" -path (Get-ChildItem $tempFile) | Select-Object Matches
                #Select-String -pattern "<dc:subject>.*</dc:subject>" -path (Get-ChildItem $tempFile) | Select-Object Matches
                #Select-String -pattern "<dc:date>.*</dc:date>" -path (Get-ChildItem $tempFile) | Select-Object Matches
            }
            finally
            {
                Remove-Item $tempFile;
            }
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    $archive.Dispose();
}
}
```

It's a modified version of code that I found on the internet and helped me to find strings inside zip files.

My intention now is to extract metadata from zip files using this code.

I don't understand how can I display the two types of information in separate lines. If you run the script with only one `Select-String...` pipeline line active, the code works as expected. If you activate (uncomment) the second `Select-String...` pipeline line, the second type of information (the `<dc:title>` value) is not displayed and instead there is a blank line.

Please help me:

1) How can I also display the `dc:title` value using the `Select-String | Select-Object` mechanism that I used in the code.

2) How can I output all the data in a table format, so the table would look something like this:

```
* ZIP Filename  * DC Title   *
* zipfile01.zip * Bla Bla 01 *
* zipfile02.zip * Bla Bla 02 *
* zipfile03.zip * Bla Bla 03 *
```

This format of output would be the most usable for me.

Answer (score 1):

The console "view" for pipeline-objcts is created based on the first object (which only have a `Path`-property). The second object is missing a `Path`-property which is why you see a blank line. If you had commented out the first `Select-String ..`-line (that shows `Path`), then the second line would work.

Objects sent through the pipeline should have the same set of properties so avoid using `select-object` with different property-sets. Ex:

```
.....

$tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();
try
{
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($archiveEntry, $tempFile, $true);
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::
    $windowsStyleArchiveEntryName = $archiveEntry.FullName.Replace('/', '\');

    Select-String -pattern "<dc:title>(.*)</dc:title>" -path (Get-ChildItem $tempFile) | Select-Object @{n="Zip FileName";e={$zipArchive.Name}}, @{Name="DC Title";Expression={ $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}}
}
finally
{
    Remove-Item $tempFile;
}

.....
```

To output all the metadata, you should create an object that includes all the values. Ex:

```
$tempFile = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName();
try
{
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($archiveEntry, $tempFile, $true);
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::
    $windowsStyleArchiveEntryName = $archiveEntry.FullName.Replace('/', '\');

    #Avoid multiple reads
    $content = Get-Content $tempFile

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        "Zip Filename" = $zipArchive.Name
        "DC Title" = if($content -match '<dc:title>(.*)</dc:title>') { $Matches[1] } else { $null }
        "DC Subject" = if($content -match '<dc:subject>(.*)</dc:subject>') { $Matches[1] } else { $null }
        "DC Date" = if($content -match '<dc:date>(.*)</dc:date>') { $Matches[1] } else { $null }
    }


}
finally
{
    Remove-Item $tempFile;
}

....
```

Ex. output

```
Zip Filename DC Subject DC Title      DC Date
------------ ---------- --------      -------
test.zip     Subject    O M G         5/18/2016
```

If you really want to force separate views (will get ugly), then you need to send he objects to `| Out-Default` to create a new view every time, ex:

```
Select-String -pattern "<dc:title>.*</dc:title>" -path (Get-ChildItem $tempFile) | Select-Object @{Name="Path";Expression={Join-Path $archivePath (Split-Path $windowsStyleArchiveEntryName -Parent)}} | Out-Default
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Frode F. It looks better, but there is still a problem
When using `$Matches[1]` I don't get the match captured value to be displayed in the table. I thought that maybe the match routine didn't find the pattern, but I'm sure it did because when i changed `$Matches[1]` to `$Matches[0]` I got the "/" value in the column for each file that actually got the text that was supposed to be matched. Could you please help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Please update the question with what you've tried, the output and desired output (include an example with `$matches[0]` etc. too.). It's hard for me to debug without knowing what the input looks like. Myabe you could share one of the tempfiles on pastebin or something (extracted from a test-zip without any senstivie data)? `if($content -match '<dc:title>(.*)</dc:title>') { $Matches[0] }` should Return `<dc:title>some value</dc:title>`, while `$Matches[1]` would only ouptut `some value`. If `$matches[0]` only Returns `/` then there's something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

i know it's not the answer you were looking for, but as a temporary workaround, you may be able to combine the two commands into one like this

```
Select-String -pattern "<dc:title>.*</dc:title>" -path (Get-ChildItem $tempFile) | Select-Object Matches, @{Name="Path";Expression={Join-Path $archivePath (Split-Path $windowsStyleArchiveEntryName -Parent)}}
```

Comment: Thanks, Anthony, but this method would not solve my problem. Your answer led me to understand that I need to update my question.

The 1st "Select-String" with "<dc:title>" is actually used as kind of a unique key for me, because I know all the files got this tag in their meta-data. I don't want to include the filename and the actual "<dc:title>" at the same output line.


The finished code would include a lot more dc tags ("<dc:creator>", "<dc:subject>" and etc.), and each tag need its own seperate line.